# Splitting a cube into 6 planes

Tags: scripting

This is toy example, but I'm fairly new to blender. I want to be able to programmatically take an object and decompose the faces into child objects. I suspect a simple example like a cube will let me debug any issues as I develop the script.

Comment: What do you mean by "child objects"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with the following script:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

# get the object
o = bpy.context.object

# create a bmesh from object data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(o.data)

# split using all edges
bmesh.ops.split_edges(bm, edges=bm.edges)

# put back bm data into object data
bm.to_mesh(o.data)
bm.free()
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.split_edges).